# How to programmatically determine which geometric shape a svg path belongs to?

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, flowchart

I have paths in SVG file with `d` attributes with values like

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="border:1px solid red" >  
<path stroke="black" fill="red" d="M 48.75521890547264 45.77014427860697 Q 48.756218905472636 45.77114427860697 50.24875621890547 45.77114427860697 Q 51.74129353233831 45.77114427860697 55.72139303482587 46.26865671641791 Q 59.701492537313435 46.766169154228855 64.17910447761194 46.766169154228855 Q 68.65671641791045 46.766169154228855 73.6318407960199 47.2636815920398 Q 78.60696517412936 47.76119402985075 82.08955223880596 47.76119402985075 Q 85.57213930348259 47.76119402985075 88.55721393034827z" />
</svg>
```

etc.

I want to classify this path into geometric shapes like circle, rectangle, ellipse etc programmatically.When i mean programmatically i mean no image processing techniques should be involved i.e strict requirement. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As seen from your example code used  `Quadratic Bezier Curves`. Curves using Bezier curves are usually not written manually.
It’s easier to do this in any vector editor, or use online Bezier curve generators.

Like for example [this](https://smooth.ie/blogs/news/svg-wavey-transitions-between-sections) generator:

[image]

In more detail, what all the commands for creating [path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) and Bezier curves mean can be studied [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

**Update**

A quote from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) that explains the principle of constructing a quadratic Bezier curve

> The other type of Bezier curve, the quadratic curve called with Q, is
>   actually a simpler curve than the cubic one. It requires one control
>   point which determines the slope of the curve at both the start point
>   and the end point. It takes two parameters: the control point and the
>   end point of the curve. Note that the co-ordinate deltas for q are
>   both relative to the previous point (that is, dx and dy are not
>   relative to dx1 and dy1).
>
> `Q x1 y1, x y (or q dx1 dy1, dx dy)`

[image]

```html
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 10 80 Q 95 10 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that actually answers the question being asked.

Comment: @RobertLongson Then in this case, please give your version of the answer to the question of how to decompose the Bezier curve into geometric figures

Comment: @RobertLongson Maybe you are right formally, but I saw that the user needs to be given the right direction in the study and construction of Bezier curves